# database error keeps radomly appearing in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a working CodeIgniter code but once in a while i get an error.

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 347

It only pops up once in a while but it is so annoying.
Anything i can do about this?

Because it was asked here is the Loader code surrounding the error

```
public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL)
    {
        // Grab the super object
        $CI =& get_instance();

        // Do we even need to load the database class?
        if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset($CI->db) AND is_object($CI->db))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');

        if ($return === TRUE)
        {
            return DB($params, $active_record);
        }

        // Initialize the db variable.  Needed to prevent
        // reference errors with some configurations
        $CI->db = '';

        // Load the DB class
        $CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of Loader.php ?

Comment: is there any problems with your hosting provider? as in a maximum amount of connections per second/minute/hour this may result in that error.

Comment: I doubt if it is a PHP error.

Comment: updated the question with Loader code

Comment: If you use codeigniter, please use enable_profiler to check the error. And post it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was my host not being able to handle alot of database requests. We are working on getting a better connection